# Why my docker compose file only works on port 80 not other ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have created a VM in a cloud and connect to it via ssh. I write a compose file and my problem is that it is only working on port 80, not other ports that I have specified here.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.graylogweb.address=:9000
      - --entrypoints.syslogtcp.address=:1514
      - --entrypoints.syslogudp.address=:1514/udp
      - --entrypoints.gelftcp.address=:12201
      - --entrypoints.gelfudp.address=:12201/udp
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://docker-socket-proxy:2375
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --api
ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 9000:9000
      - 1514:1514
      - 1514:1514/udp
      - 12201:12021
      - 12201:12201/udp
```

When I use docker ps command I only see that port 80 is working.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
aebd4cccdcb0   traefik:v2.3                           "/entrypoint.sh --en…"   20 seconds ago   Up 19 seconds   80/tcp     traefik_traefik.1.fnaam7nc7aj3aqsfhlbs0vm0o
941dbb9f712d   tecnativa/docker-socket-proxy:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes   2375/tcp   traefik_docker-socket-proxy.1.adgj8n1pklmhvpc36dcvx1ypz
```

Comment: did you allowed inbound traffic for container port in cloud service provider.

Comment: In the question, 'ports:` is at the first column; it should be aligned with `image:`and `command:`.  Is that a copy-paste error?  Can you connect to any of the ports, ignoring the `docker ps` output?